# Composer is using https instead of ssh (for GitLab)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, composer-php

When using a `composer.json` like this to install a private package:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "foobar/example-package": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@gitlab.com:foobar/example-package.git"
    }]
}
```

Composer tries to use `https` instead of `ssh` for some reason:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Failed to download foobar/example-package:The "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/foobar%2Fexample-package" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)      
Your credentials are required to fetch private repository metadata (git@gitlab.com:foobar/example-package.git)
A token will be created and stored in "…\composer\home/auth.json", your password will never be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://gitlab.com/profile/applications
Username:
```

Even when using `-vvv` there is no indication why Composer would need to access the repository via `https` - while it is perfectly possible to push and pull code to the private repository via `ssh` (using the private key stored in the SSH agent).

This happens with Composer 1.x and 2.x. Is there no way to *only* use `ssh` for operations like this? This problem also seems specific to GitLab as I have never encountered it with GitHub repositories for example.

Comment: Try to use `git` instead of `vcs` as repository type.

Comment: I don't use composer, but this turned up in a simple google search: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#github-protocols - is there something similar for gitlab, given that this particular configuration item is specific to github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check "[Install composer packages from private repository from GitLab](https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/install-composer-packages-from-private-repository-from-gitlab-b43597c409c0)" from [Syed Sirajul Islam Anik](https://twitter.com/sirajul_anik)

> So, to install a package from GitLab which is not a public repository will need a Personal Access Token.
> You can issue your PAT by going to Profile Icon `> Settings > Access Token`. Then to issue a new PAT, write a name and select a scope `api/read_api, read_api` is a minimum. `api` will work too. If you want to set an expiry, can put value in that. Then press the Create personal access token Button.
>
> Next, from the terminal. Run the following command.
>
> composer config --global --auth gitlab-token.gitlab.com PAT_TOKEN
>
> Replace the `PAT_TOKEN` with the token you found from the above process. And if you’re using a self-hosted GitLab, then you’ll need to change the URL `gitlab.com` to your self-hosted URL.
>
> Then, in your composer.json file, add the following snippet.
>
> ```json
> "repositories": [
>    {
>        "type": "vcs",
>        "url": "git@gitlab.com:namespace/repo-name.git"
>    }
> ]
> ```

Or, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744374/composer-is-using-https-instead-of-ssh-for-gitlab/70512499#comment119746677_67744374), use `"type": "git"` instead of `"vcs"`:

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@gitlab.com:namespace/repo-name.git"
    }
]
```

> If your `composer.json` file already contains the repository key, then add the object to it.
>
> Finally,
>
> ```
> composer require vendor-name/package-name
> ```

In other words, even though the URL is SSH, you still need a PAT (token) to use the HTTPS GitLab API invoked by `composer`.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like with GitLab composer does indeed still require API access via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [@rob006](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5812455/rob006) changing `vcs` to `git` will solve the issue.

he/she mentioned that in comments and maybe some people don't notice that, so I repeat it as an answer maybe help someone.